# Keep setInterval running while tab is completely closed

Tags: javascript, time, setinterval, clock

Trying to make a real-time clock that uses setInterval (centisecond based) but I want it to run when the tab is not open or even when the computer is off. Is this even possible? If you have heard of the game cookie clicker, I'm pretty sure it at least runs when the tab is completely closed out of, so how do I replicate it, and if I cant, are there any other methods I can use to make a digital clock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to run *code* while a tab is closed or the machine is off. The best you could do is to periodically save information to `localStorage`, and then, whenever the script runs again, retrieve the saved information from `localStorage` and run all the calculations necessary to get up-to-date. Or, if it's as simple as a date, you might just check `Date.now()` every time the tab is opened.

Here's a very simplistic implementation:

```
const info = localStorage.savedInfo
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.savedInfo)
  : { count: 0, date: Date.now() };
const now = Date.now();
if (info.date < now) {
  info.count += Math.floor((now - info.date) / 1000);
  info.date = now;
}
function tick() {
  info.count++;
  console.log(info.count);
  info.date = Date.now();
  localStorage.savedInfo = JSON.stringify(info);
  setTimeout(tick, 1000);
}
tick();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gn9128ea/1/

Comment: What does Date.now() return, its a pretty long number, do you know what it is written as? milliseconds, centiseconds etc.

Comment: `Date.now()` returns the number of milliseconds since the epoch.